# Java String trim - how to minimize

Tags: java, string, sonarqube, trim

Java doc says `String.trim()` Returns a copy of the string.

I have below code in my method, it does `trim` as mentioned and results in creating new string thrice.

```
String foo = getFoo(storedProcedureResult);
if(foo !=null && !foo.trim().isEmpty()){ // --> creates new string
  if(foo.trim().substring(1).equals("bar")){ // --> creates new string
  } else if(foo.trim().substring(4,6).equals("bar")){ // --> creates new string
  }
}
```

I made an attempt to minimize this with below code:

```
 String foo = getFoo(storedProcedureResult);
    if(foo !=null && !(foo=foo.trim()).isEmpty()){ // --> creates new string only once
      if(foo.substring(1).equals("bar")){ 
      } else if(foo.substring(4,6).equals("bar")){ 
      }
    }
```

Now, Sonar reports `Assignments should not be made from within sub-expressions`. How do I efficiently minimize the usage of `trim` in my method? I am bothering  because this method is being used in production and invoked 250+ times per second and should not create more `String` objects unnecessarily.

Comment: Try as foo = foo == null ? "" : foo.trim();
if(!foo.isEmpty())

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding but can't you do `String trimmedFoo = foo.trim()` and then just use that?

Comment: @Aequitas, if foo is `null` you will have an NPE here.

Comment: `String foo = getFoo(storedProcedureResult).trim();`

Comment: substring() also creates a new String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write:

```
String foo = getFoo(storedProcedureResult);
if(foo != null) foo = foo.trim();
if(foo !=null && !foo.isEmpty()){
  if(foo.substring(1).equals("bar")){ 
  } else if(foo.substring(4,6).equals("bar")){ 
  }
}
```

You can also create an utility method for this:

```
static String safeTrim(String s) {
    return s == null ? null : s.trim();
}
```

And use it:

```
String foo = safeTrim(getFoo(storedProcedureResult));
```

Actually such method exists in [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#trim%28java.lang.String%29).

More generic solution would be to convert null string to empty via the special method:

```
static String nullToEmpty(String s) {
    return s == null ? "" : s;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
String foo = nullToEmpty(getFoo(storedProcedureResult)).trim();
if(!foo.isEmpty()){
  if(foo.substring(1).equals("bar")){ 
  } else if(foo.substring(4,6).equals("bar")){ 
  }
}
```

Actually such method is available in [Google Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/master/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#nullToEmpty%28java.lang.String%29).

Finally you may use Java-8 [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) if you don't want to create/use non-standard methods:

```
String foo = Optional.ofNullable(getFoo(storedProcedureResult))
                     .map(String::trim).orElse("");
if(!foo.isEmpty()){
  if(foo.substring(1).equals("bar")){ 
  } else if(foo.substring(4,6).equals("bar")){ 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split your first `if` statement. The following assumes you want to retain the original `foo`.

```
String foo = getFoo(storedProcedureResult);
if (foo != null) {
    String trimmedFoo = foo.trim();
    if (! trimmedFoo.isEmpty()) {
        if (trimmedFoo.substring(1).equals("bar")) {
            // do something here
        } else if (trimmedFoo.length() >= 6 && trimmedFoo.substring(4,6).equals("bar")) {
            // do something here
        }
    }
}
```

The code is also guarding against `IndexOutOfBoundsException` for strings shorter than 6 characters.